# php returns wrong result for Year and Week when calculating from 16th sept 2014

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
$date = strtotime("2014-09-16");
echo "Date=".date('YW', strtotime('+15 weeks',$date));
```

This results in 201401 which is obviously wrong.

I am building a holiday calendar that requires spanning over a date period
which spans over a year and this does not work. It seems there is a problem
within the way date where there are 53 weeks in a year.

Any help / workaround would be great.

Comment: well php only returns what you write ... php doesnt have AI at that moment

Comment: You may want to try `DateTime` and the related classes instead of working with unix timestamps. In my experience they are a bit better with special cases.

Comment: 2014 is a 52 week year according to ISO 8601

Comment: Did you check whether `$date` is parsed as intended? I tend to use `DateTime::add()` instead of `strtotime()` as it leaves fewer possibilities for misinterpretation.

Comment: ISO_8601 is confusing - The week definition is "the week starting with the Monday in the period 29 December – 4 January." i.e the first week of next year contains part of this year.

Answer (score 1):

You have "selected" last week in current year AND new weak in next year. Date is still in year 2014, but week belongs to iso-8601 year 2015. So if you wish to format date to ISO-8601 year, and not date year, use `o` instead of `Y`:

```
$date = strtotime("2014-09-16");
echo "Date=".date('oW', strtotime('+15 weeks',$date));
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/194433)**</kbd>